# The meaning of „wohl“ in „Er hoffte, dass sie sich im Ozean wohl fühlte.“

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is from a children‘s story and has been translated as,

> He hoped she was happy in the ocean.

However, the definitions I find for „wohl“ do not include „happy.“ That would be more, „glücklich,“ I assume. The definitions for „wohl“ all connote a sense of well being and comfort. So the sentence could be translated as,

> He hoped she was doing well in the ocean.“

but that seems to convey a rather weak sentiment given that the „he“ very much loves the „she“ in this story. How would others translate this sentence? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds fine to me.

Answer (score 3):

The sentence is okay. I would suggest not looking up the word "wohl", but the verb "wohlfühlen" ([Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wohlfuehlen), [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/wohlf%C3%BChlen)).

It is true that it is not a very literal translation, a more literal one would be "dass sie im Ozean glücklich war", but there is not a huge difference between "being happy" and "feeling well/comfortable".

Answer (score 2):

Well, the problem is that for the German terms *"sich wohl fühlen", "glücklich sein", "sich freuen", "fröhlich sein"* and similar terms there seems to be no exactly matching translations in English.

For me, *"being happy"* describes a bright and fresh feeling that I associate with sunshine and children jumping around. Only *"fröhlich sein"* has a meaning that is in this range, and also *"ausgelassen sein",* but that is again quite a way from *"glücklich sein".*

For me, most of these German terms tend to describe a warm, cozy feeling of feeling comfort, especially *"sich wohl fühlen"* and of course *"sich geborgen fühlen",* which is also a good bit away from *"glücklich sein",* but in the opposite direction from *"ausgelassen sein".*

The problem I have with the term *"to do well"* is the verb *"do"* that occurs in it. *"Do"* describes an action, something that someone actively does. But *"sich wohl fühlen"* describes something that one feels. You don't have to do anything to feel something, so it happens in a much more passive mode.

I would use this translation:

> Er hoffte, dass sie sich im Ozean wohl fühlte.
> He hoped, that she feels fine in the ocean.

(I'm not sure about the comma, English is a foreign language to me.)

DeepL offers this translation, which is also fine:

> He hoped she will be comfortable in the sea.

Your proposal was:

> He hoped she was doing well in the ocean.

That's fine, but your suggestion is more about her interaction with the sea, whereas the German sentence was about getting impressions from the ocean.

---

Btw: What children's story is this sentence from? Is it *»Herr Vogel und Frau Wal«*? I found your sentence here: https://www.thefablecottage.com/fables/herr-vogel-und-frau-wal

In the context of this story the English translation *»He hoped she was happy in the ocean.«* is perfectly fine, because in the German text also *»Er hoffte, dass sie im Ozean glücklich war« also would fit perfectly.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, it seems right that nothing in English quite captures the German here. Taking into account both responses, I would now change my mind and say that the original translation is best. The phrase “doing well” does not convey enough emotional investment. By the way, “doing“ in “doing well” is quite passive. I found the story here: https://www.thegermanproject.com/stories

Comment: Notice that "wohl fühlen" and "wohlfühlen" are two different things/activities! A "viel versprechender" politician is of a different kind than a "vielversprechender" politician.

Comment: @bakunin: Bei *»Er ist ein viel versprechender Politiker«* versus *»Er ist ein vielversprechender Politiker«* gebe ich dir zu 100% recht. Aber ich erkennen keinen Unterschied zwischen *»Ich habe mich wohl gefühlt«* und *»Ich habe mich wohlgefühlt«.* Seit 2004/2006 sind beide Schreibweisen erlaubt, wobei die zusammengeschriebene die empfohlene Variante ist. Vor 2004/2006 galt die zusammengeschriebene Variante als falsch, damals hätte man *»Ich habe mich wohlgefühlt«* gar nicht schreiben dürfen.